# Java: auto-unboxing combined with casting

Tags: java, casting, autoboxing

Please help me wrap my head around why this doesn't work. (It's not a practical problem, it's a mental excercise for the OCPJP exam.)

```html
public class ImplicitConversions {

Integer iBoxed;
short sPrimitive = (short)iBoxed;

}
```

//compiler error: incompatible types; required: short, found: Integer

I'm assuming the compiler tries to cast first without (or before) unboxing, whereas for example an arithmetic operation (iBoxed+iBoxed) will unbox it first. Therefore, is it safe to say that auto-boxing/unboxing has its place in the the order of operations (Unary, Arithmetic, Relational, Logical, Conditional, Assignment) and where is it exactly?

I've been reading about casting conversion in source below (to make sure I'm compatible with 1.6), but this one eludes me. Thanks.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#20232

Comment: you're casting to preemptive data type this is not allowed

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy How should that possibly work?  There is no inheritance relationship between `Integer` and `Short`.  `short sPrimitive = (Short) iBoxed;` won't even compile and while `short sPrimitive = (Short) (Object) iBoxed;` does compile, it is for no good that the compiler's type checking was circumvented.  A runtime-exception will be thrown.

Comment: you're right. I don't know why I said so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
(short)iBoxed
```

is a stand-alone expression that doesn't depend on its context. What you are trying to do is cast an `Integer` reference value to a `short` primitive value. [That's just not a casting context that is allowed.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5) (See the table further down in the chapter.)

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` has a method `shortValue()`. Use this instead:

```
short sPrimitive = iBoxed.shortValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

An auto-boxing/unboxing expression cannot be combined with a <s>wider- or</s> narrower-range cast.

However, you can double-cast the `iBoxed` variable:

```
short sPrimitive = (short) (int) iBoxed;
```

First the `iBoxed` variable is auto-unboxed to an `int`, and then the `int` is converted to a `short`.

Comment: Integer integerWrapper = 1;  long i3 = (long) integerWrapper; // OK!  long i4 = integerWrapper; // OK